# If a generated subgroup is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I would like to make a similar question to question "Exercise on generated subgroup":

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H\leq G$, $H$ cyclic with $|H|=exp(G)$. If $x\in C_{G}(H)\smallsetminus H$, then is $\langle x,H\rangle $ cyclic? If this statement is true, how to prove it?

Comment: Can you explain your use of the `\smallsetminus` notation, and what it means here? Did you mean to simply write $x\in C_G(H)\setminus H$ (`\setminus`)?

Comment: @amWhy, I think it is the small symbol for difference of sets.

Comment: @amWhy: I'm 99% sure that it means $x \in C_G(H)$ and $x \not\in H$... It's in the name of the symbol, "set minus".

Comment: @amWhy many people think `\smallsetminus` is more aesthetically pleasing, for instance [this person](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87107/redefining-smallsetminus-by-smaller-setminus)

Comment: Very well, @Myself, I will respect the OP's choice and return the edit..

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to provide a counterexample. It is not possible for $\langle x, H \rangle$ to be cyclic given the other conditions, even without $x \in C_{G}(H)$. Since $|H| = \exp(G),$ the only way that $\langle x,H \rangle$ could be cyclic would be if $\langle x,H \rangle = H,$ which would force $x \in H,$ but you have assumed $x \not \in H.$

Answer (score 1):

No - consider $G = C_2 \times C_2$, and $H$ an index 2 subgroup.